# Best way to abstract wrapping C error handling with exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

It is not uncommon for a useful C library to not provide C++ bindings. It's easy to call C from C++, but among other issues, a C++ project probably wants exceptions, rather than numerical error return values.

Is there any particular convention or trick for converting to exceptions without including an `if` and `throw` with each function call?

I wrote this solution for wrapping gphoto2 calls. Having to wrap the templated function in a macro is awkward (but the function name is kind of important for error messages; the logic here is similar to `perror`).

Is there a better technique, or any open source project that does this particularly well?

```cpp
#include <gphoto2/gphoto2.h>
#include <string>

class Gphoto2Error : public std::exception {
  private:
    std::string message;

  public:
    Gphoto2Error(std::string func, int err) {
        message = func + ": " + std::string(gp_result_as_string(err));
    }
    const char *what() const throw() {
        return message.c_str();
    }
};

template <typename F, typename... Args>
void _gpCall(const char *name, F f, Args... args) {
    int ret = f(args...);
    if (ret != GP_OK) {
        throw Gphoto2Error(name, ret);
    }
}
#define gpCall(f, ...) ((_gpCall(#f, ((f)), __VA_ARGS__)))

int main() {
    GPContext *ctx = gp_context_new();
    Camera *camera;
    gpCall(gp_camera_new, &camera);
    gpCall(gp_camera_init, camera, ctx);
}
```

Comment: I see someone voted to close as "primary opinion based". Any particular critiques or suggestions to improve the question? Although "best" is clearly a matter of opinion (perhaps a word I should have avoided), it seems reasonable to ask what solutions are used for this particular problem (of which I've written one, but I'm sure many others have run into the same issue), and if there are any particularly common conventions.

Comment: I didn't .-) I think your intention is brilliant. The `if` "must" be somewhere. `RAII` and throw if there's truly an exception. You'll be able to do explicit initialization in your constructors on top of that (with no extra checking - since it's all covered already).

Comment: I didn't VTC, but how would you quantify "better"?  Fewer lines of code?  Less likely for a developer to do it wrong?  Lower run time impact?  Less memory usage?  Also the _any open source project_ request is definitely off topic ("recommend a software library").

Comment: But you *do* intend to pack that into a class or a set of classes, do you? I wouldn't leave the bare macros for the user, even though this means duplicating all the functions of the libraries as member functions of the class(es) (but you'd use your macro inside these member functions, of course).

Comment: Create wrapper functions for all the C functions, which convert error codes to exceptions.

Comment: @Aconcagua My current use case is just for writing a program using the library, and making the code neater and shorter. So it's not meant to be exposed in a library. Writing full C++ bindings would of course mean writing wrapper functions as methods of several classes that handle this conversion among other things (likely using some abstraction like this internally to avoid duplication).

Comment: Some kind of code generator to write C++ wrapper functions could be a solution. Frees you from manually adding wrappers each time the C API is extended.

Comment: @IanD.Scott Depending on how many calls you make into that library, it might still be worth the effort – for sake of readability of your own code. Of course, if there are just some very view calls...

Answer (score 5):

Since it’s possible (in practice, via `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` or `typeid`) to recover the name of a function to which a template parameter refers, I would (in C++17) write

```
template<auto &F,class ...AA>
void gpCall(AA &&...aa) {
  if(int ret=f(aa...); ret!=GP_OK)
    throw Gphoto2Error(/* … */,ret);
}
int main() {
  GPContext *ctx = gp_context_new();
  Camera *camera;
  gpCall<gp_camera_new>(&camera);
  gpCall<gp_camera_init>(camera, ctx);
  return 0;
}
```

The expression to obtain the function name is implementation-dependent, but a basic approach that produces usable results (albeit with extra text) in many cases is to add

```
#include<typeinfo>
template<auto&> Symbol;
```

and write `typeid(Symbol<F>).name()`.

Comment: How can `typeid` be used to get the name of the function?

Comment: @geza: Instantiate a class template with the function pointer/reference and ask for its [name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name).  Demangling may be required (or your implementation could just return garbage, but that’s rare).

Comment: @geza [`typid(...).name()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name). Problem is "implementation defined", which might limit portability (not an issue in current case, as it appears...)

Comment: @DavisHerring: how can this be used inside the function (just like `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`)?

Comment: @geza `typeid(F).name()`. Solely, the 'garbage' case is perhaps less uncommon than expected: `typeid(memcpy).name()` yielded `FPvS_PKvyE` with MinGW on my system...

Comment: @geza: I don’t understand the question—do you just mean `typeid(MyTemplate<F>).name()`?  It doesn’t work on *normal* parameters that are pointers or references to functions, of course; you have to go to a backtrace-like library for that.

Comment: @Aconcagua: where is the string `memcpy` in that string?

Comment: @geza Well, that's the problem with "implementation defined". With one compiler, you might get what you want, with another not (me providing an example for the latter case).

Comment: @Aconcagua: That’s “demangling required”, not “garbage”: you asked about the type **of** `memcpy`, not about a class template specialization that refers to it.

Comment: @DavisHerring: can you put an expression here (which is inside `gpCall`), which contains the name of `F`?

Comment: @Aconcagua: I don't think that any compiler will put `memcpy` there. It should contain type information, not the name.

Comment: This ongoing discussion makes it obvious that the answer lacks an example of how to apply typeid correctly here...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Given the multiple strategies that might (need to) be pursued, I would think that a separate question.  I did [provide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56995824/best-way-to-abstract-wrapping-c-error-handling-with-exceptions/56998064#comment100540401_56998064) the simplest case above; use it with `template<auto&> struct MyTemplate;`.

Comment: @DavisHerring: But this expression doesn't give the name of `F`, does it? Will it result, for example, `gp_camera_new` (or some mangled version of this)?

Comment: @geza We need some additional dummy template to get it work, something like `template <auto &F> struct Name { };` With this I get with `typeid(Name<F>).name()`: `4NameIL_Z6memcpyEE` with the parts around 'memcpy' being the same for different functions with different type...

Comment: @Aconcagua: thanks, now I see this nice trick. Maybe it's worth putting this information into the answer itself.

Comment: @geza: I added it, but I still think a separate question would be more useful.